# css grids layout - mobile first approach

Tags: css, css-grid

Why do we need to define the grid for mobile?

What is the advantage of doing so?

Check this example: [common layouts with ccs grids on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Realizing_common_layouts_using_CSS_Grid_Layout)

So, we could have the same results for mobile without defining a grid, just defining the grid at the first breakpoint would do the job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're correct for the most part. With the example in that tutorial, there is no difference if you declare the grid at the first breakpoint. The only differences are semantic.

Some of the benefits:

**Consistency and clarity:**
Your code will be more consistent and easier to intuit what is going on if the same layout method is used across all your breakpoints. Good css is easy to read, even for people who are not familiar with the project, who are not familiar with your coding style. If you intend to use grid layout, it should be consistent and used across the board.

**Complexity of layout:**
The example doesn't require grid layout for mobile, but that doesn't mean that will always be the case. As you iterate over the design, you may need to add more complexity later. If the structure is in place from the get-go, the refactoring process becomes easier.

Still, there is an argument to be made for only including code that is absolutely necessary to implement the correct layout. It's really down to personal preference whether you include it or not.

Comment: Thank you Daniel, this helps me to understand why they did so.